# Scheduling Airflow DAGs both in time and using Datasets

Tags: python, dataset, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

In Airflow, how would you configure a DAG to be scheduled both hourly (to work with time intervals) and after a Dataset has been updated (after the execution_date) ?

For instance, I would like to consumes some hourly data in DAG B, which is made available less frequently by another DAG A (with rsync). There is thus no point to trigger all the hourly dag runs of DAG B before DAG A has produced the dataset that contains hourly data.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create your dag with the schedule interval `hourly` to trigger the hourly runs.

Then if you want to trigger other runs based on external actions, you have multiple option:

- if you want to trigger a run based on an action of another dag (creating a dataset in the second dag), you can add a task for the second dag using the operator `TriggerDagRunOperator` to trigger a run of the first one when the the action task is finished.
- if you want to trigger a run based on an action outside Airflow, you can send an http POST request to Airflow API to trigger the run whenever you want ([doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run))